# How to retrieve contents of ... as list of calls?

Tags: r, parsing, arguments, expression, substitution

If I want to see what expression was passed into a function, I can retrieve it using `substitute`.

```
f <- function(x)
{
  substitute(x)  
}

f(sin(pi))
## sin(pi)
```

(`f` returns an object of class `call`.  `substitute` is usually combined with `deparse` to turn it into a character vector, but I don't care about that here.)

I want to repeat this with arguments in `...`.  This attempt only returns the first argument:

```
g <- function(...)
{
  substitute(...)
}

g(sin(pi), cos(pi / 2))
## sin(pi)
```

This attempt throws an error:

```
h <- function(...)
{
  lapply(..., subsitute)
}

h(sin(pi), cos(pi / 2))
## Error in match.fun(FUN) :
##   'cos(pi/2)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

This attempt throws a different error:

```
i <- function(...)
{
  lapply(list(...), substitute)
}

i(sin(pi), cos(pi / 2))

## Error in lapply(list(...), substitute) : 
##   '...' used in an incorrect context
```

How do I retrieve the expressions that I passed into `...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to keep objetcts of class call:

```
i <- function(...)
{
  l <- match.call()
  l <- as.list(l)
  l <- l[-1]
  l
}

i <- function(...)
{
  l <- match.call()
  l[[1]] <- as.name("expression")
  l
}
i(sin(pi), cos(pi/2))
```

Or maybe you just need the match.call depending what you want to do after.
hth

Comment: Ah yes.  I forgot about `match.call`.  `as.list(match.call())[-1]` is what I want.

Comment: I like this version more :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
substitute_multi <- function(...) {
   f <- function(e1, ...) {
      if (missing(e1)) return(NULL)
      else return(list(substitute(e1), substitute_multi(...)))
   }
   unlist(f(...))
}
```

Which gives for example:

```
substitute_multi(x, g(y), 1+2+3)
## [[1]]
## x
## 
## [[2]]
## g(y)
## 
## [[3]]
## 1 + 2 + 3
```

You may also call `as.expression` on the result to get an `expression` object.

IMHO, this solution is not as elegant as the other one, but gives some insight on how `...` deals with function arguments. :)